# SSRS Subscription failure rsProcessingAborted

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have subscriptions that are failing to run giving the error:

> Failure sending mail: An error has occurred during report processing.Mail will not be resent.

The report runs fine when requested manually through the server so I know the datasource and connection work.

Inside the SSRS database the only information I can get is from the ExecutionLogStorage saying:

> rsProcessingAborted

The ExecutionLogStorage table also shows the TimeStart and TimeEnd being 1 second apart, on a report that takes 2+ minutes to run manually. The report has not failed a single time when running manually, only fails through the subscription.

The windows event viewer does contain some errors about a TERADATA extension but they do not coincide with the subscription failures.

The logs located in \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.Reporting\Reporting Services\LogFiles do not even contain an entry for that subscription during failure at all.

I'm not sure where to go for more information, I need to know why this subscription is failing, we have the workaround of manually running the report and manually emailing it out after converted to excel but that's not a viable solution going forward.

Answer (score 3):

Some other places you could check are:

SSRS Log:

```
c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

You could try enabling verbose logging (level 4) here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ReportingServicesService.exe.config
```

Look for this tag:

```
<switches>
  <add name="DefaultTraceSwitch" value="4" />
</switches>
```

I'm fighting very similar issue but to make it a bit complex, my subscription fails only every other time or so and runs fine sometimes. So far I ruled out:

- No. of parallel SSRS sessions
- Memory pressure on DB server & Report
- Server  Kicking off the subscription directly vs remotely(running
  the agent job)

Sorry, I do not have a good answer for you but this issue seems to bother more than few people.

**Update:**
I found out that the Subscription was a created by a windows user who is no longer valid (ID expired). Updating the Subscription owner fixed it.

-- List SSRS users (check to make sure the new Owner exists in this list)

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE UserName IN ('DomainName\_SSRSServiceAccount')
```

-- DFGRYH-DFGRYH--DFGRYH-DFGRYH

-- Identify the subscription whose ownership you would like to edit

```
SELECT *
FROM Subscriptions
WHERE OwnerID = 'DFGRYH-DFGRYH--DFGRYH-DFGRYH'
    AND Description = 'Send e-mail to RichG@DomainName.com'
ORDER BY LastRunTime
    ,LastStatus
```

-- Update the Subscription with new Owner, the change should reflect on the SSRS reports

```
UPDATE Subscriptions
SET OwnerID = 'DFGRYH-DFGRYH--DFGRYH-DFGRYH'
WHERE SubscriptionID = 'B33A78FC-933D-47DB-AB50-43D36B24C0B8'
```

Comment: Did this issue ever get resolved? I am having it as well.